# iOS Offline Storage for Chat history

Tags: ios, offline-storage

I want to store the offline messages, in Chatting Application for Chat history, with text, image, Video thumb with Video url link and location (lat,long) values.

How to store in offline and maintain DataBase?

Comment: you can use SQLiteCipher if you want encryption as well. Just integrate it with your app .You can find a tutorial on it .

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for offline storage in iOS

> 1. SQLite
> 2. CoreData
> 3. NSCoding

For this particular task, I believe CoreData will do a better job. It is secure.

You can start with CoreData with the following [tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=core%20data%20introduction). I suggest you to watch the following [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/214/) for best practices in core data.

Comment: Can you give any Offline Storage sample Example. either SQLite or CoreData.

Comment: I gave the link for tutorial right. For coredata, you can click on tutorial to go to the link

Comment: i know tutorial link, but i want to example .

Comment: @ShravanKumar Teegala example here might go to long.You can study and raise your issue here stack has a big iOS team to solve any issue you have.